# Author year citation without comma

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, apa-style

I am relatively new to the `natbib` package. I was wondering if there is an option to remove the 'comma' between an author name and year. For example, using the style `apalike`, I get (Name, year), but I want it to appear as (Name year).

Comment: It would be easy to do with `biblatex`.

Comment: Even if I think what you want to achieve is rather easy to achieve (see my suggestion below), I would second @Bernard and recommend checking out `biblatex`. It is so much more powerful and flexible. And given that you are new to `natbib`, as you say, I would invest in the switch and start reaping the benefits.

Comment: @Bernard -- "It would be easy to do with biblatex" -- Is the instruction `\setcitestyle{aysep={}}` not easy enough? :-)

Comment: @ Mico: Sure, but I couldn't make such an naswer knowing not `natbib`. I meant it's easier to customise `biblatex` than to put hands on a `.bst` file.

Comment: @Bernard - The OP did mention the use of the `natbib` package. The form of the citation call-out -- including the presence or absence of a comma between the author and year labels -- is controlled by `natbib`, not the `bst` file.

Comment: @Mico: Isee. Didn't know the details. But are all details of a bibliography layout controlled by `natbib`?

Comment: @Bernard - `natbib` is (primarily) a citation management package. When loaded, it controls most aspects of the formatting of the citation call-outs. The `bst` file does  have a role to play as well, e.g., whether names should be typeset in the regular font or using small-cap letters, say.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I will definitely check out `biblatex`.

Comment: All over the Internet, everyone keeps on saying "X is easier with biblatex", but with no examples, no helps (like makebst), or anything else.  I'm sure biblatex is easier for some definition (perhaps to package maintainers?), but certainly not in the case of helping ordinary users do ordinary customizations!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `natbib`package provides the command `\setcitestyle` that allows for some customization. The delimiter between author and year in citations is set using the key-value pair `aysep={<char>}`.

Here is an almost MWE (fill in your bib file and a prober cite key):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
   \usepackage{natbib}
   \setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
\begin{document}
   \bibliographystyle{apalike}

   \citep{<some cite key in your bib file>}

   \bibliography{<bib file>}
\end{document}
```